# Get the Venue ID from the Foursquare url

Tags: url, foursquare

Is it possible to get the Venue ID from an url?

If I have the Venue URL from the Foursquare (example: https://pt.foursquare.com/zahpee ), how do I know what is the venue ID of this location?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I dont know any solution by using the 4sq url. But when you know the url scheme - you can access the venue-id.

zahpee = name of the venue

with that information you can perform a seach:

```
GET https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?query=zahpee&intent=global
```

example response, extract:

```
response: {
venues: [
{
id: "4fc123f4e4b08acecb574b62"
name: "Zahpee"
contact: {
phone: "+553125164812"
formattedPhone: "+55 31 2516-4812"
twitter: "zahpee"
}
location: {
address: "Avenida Álvares Cabral, 1315"
crossStreet: "Santa Catarina"
lat: -19.931101175274925
lng: -43.94602344328842
cc: "BR"
city: "Belo Horizonte"
state: "MG"
country: "Brazil"
formattedAddress: [
"Avenida Álvares Cabral, 1315 (Santa Catarina)"
"Belo Horizonte, MG"
"Brazil"
]
}
```

check it easily by using the API explorer

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore

I hope this helps you.